# Communicate with main window class from CodeDom compiled code C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, function, call, codedom

As the title suggests I am having a bit of trouble communicating with my wpf application's MainWindow.cs class during runtime when the code compiles.

Context: 
This is a application I am writing for myself that utilizes CodeDom's compiler to compile code stored in xml format at runtime or in a triggered event(like a button or voice command)

The compiler is working neatly but I have been stuck at communicating with my classes from the original application.(MainWindow.cs)

I would like to be able to call functions and access variables from within the runtime compiled CodeDom Scripts. I have found method invoking but I don't quite understand how it works yet, any help would be appreciated!

Example of what I want to do:

**Main Window Class Example**

```
namespace WpfOverlay
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string AccessThis;


        public void ExampleFunctionToAccess(string InputString)
        {
            AccessThis = InputString;
        }
    }
}
```

And access that class to call **ExampleFunctionToAccess();**  from a CodeDom Compiled script/class in a different namespace (if possible I wouldn't mind having them in the same namespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you compile it at runtime has no bearing on your actual problem, what you actually want is to implement any of the myriad forms possible of IPC.

I recommend an UDP client/server approach, it's relatively easy to implement robustly.